# Minimal API - Get Request fails when sending a JSON object

Tags: rest, restsharp

I have implemented the following code generated by PostMan using RestSharp. When sending the request with Postman, the desired result is there, but when executing this code it returns with "MethodNotAllowed". Have done a lot of reading and research. I am new to the Minimal Rest API. I will also post the code at the RESTAPI side.

````
   {
      MaxTimeout = -1,
   };
   var client = new RestClient(options);
   var request = new RestRequest("https://api.votingcrowd.co.za/User/Details", Method.Get);
   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   var body = "....";
   request.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
   RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
   Console.WriteLine(response.Content);``` 

At API Side: 

```app.MapGet(RESTRoutes.UserDetails, ([FromBody] Credentials CredentialObject) => VoteAPI.User.GetUsers(CredentialObject));```
````

Comment: You usually don't use request body with GET. Either use POST or pass the necessary data using query string parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Realized that. Changed the code and it is working now.